# CBCentralManager runs in background, but eventually dies

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, background, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I successfully have `CBCentralManager` running in the background scanning for peripherals. I have the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` in a singleton method and have `App communicates using CoreBluetooth` in the .plist and like I say, it works great for hours in the background.

The problem I have, is when my app is completely killed because other apps have been used and need the memory space.
If I run other apps to flush my app, then my app is no longer woken by any of the `CBCentralManager` delegate calls.

Is there something else I need to do to make sure my app is woken back up?
Do I maybe need to have the `CBCentralManager` calls in the App Delegate?
Should I be doing something in the App Delegate when the app is backgrounded?

Thanks

Comment: HI Darren, Could you give me some core blue tooth sample code which works in the background. I have tried a lot but it is not working in the background.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the ability for your application to be launched due to a Core Blue Tooth event. Unfortunately, that isn't possible in iOS 6.0. I talked with the Apple BlueTooth engineers at WWDC 2012, and they understood the use case, and said it wasn't supported.

Perhaps they will add something in iOS 7.0.